# Can I lower the order of differential equation in this example?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y'''' + 9y'' = 18 (9x+2)$$

Can I make a substitution $$y''=p$$
and solve $$p''+ 9p = 18 (9x+2)$$
Or not ?

Comment: Yes. That is indeed valid.

Comment: As $y''$ is a derivable function and $y''''=(y'')''$, there can be no harm renaming $y''$ as $p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you are right or you can use another way by taking the integration two times
$$y'''+9y'=81x^2+36x+C_1$$
$$y''+9y=27x^3+18x^2+C_1x+C_2$$